# Alternative to `keras.backend.rnn` in order convert a TensorFlow SavedModel to tensorflow.js graph model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I currently have a trained model with custom layers that under the hood uses keras' [backend.rnn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/rnn).

When I try to convert the model using `tensorflowjs_converter==1.3.2`, the conversion process fails with the error

```
ValueError: Unsupported Ops in the model before optimization
TensorListFromTensor, TensorListStack, TensorListSetItem, TensorListReserve, TensorListGetItem
```

Which seems to indicate that TensorArray ops are not supported with tensorflow.js.

I am interested in knowing if anyone has run into this before, and figured out an alternative, compatible alternative.

Comment: As indicated by the error, the operators are not yet supported

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I am looking for an alternative way of doing the same thing, that converts.